Disable wifi-calls when entering airplane mode
I need some solution to have wifi-calls disabled when I enter airplane mode each night. In other words disable cellular and wifi-calling in one go. I do need wifi enabled for various reasons. Otherwise this would be pretty simple.
Would a shortcut be a possible way? I don't see a good mechanism for this.
Or maybe I'm missing some general obvious built-in functionality for disabling/enabling two related functions?

Not a full answer, but you can use an Automation Personal Shortcut (iOS 16.7.8) to turn off the cellular signal when activating airplane mode and to turn it on when turning airplane mode off. Unfortunately, there is not a system hook to control Wifi calling from Automation.
